# javascript/dojo method scope

Tags: javascript, module, dojo

I have created a dojo module that implements a simple shopping cart. I have a load() method that generates the dom nodes for the cart on a page and displays them. This includes a query which assigns a click event to the "remove from cart" button for each item in the cart. I want this click event to call a remove() method, also at the root level of the module, but after passing all of the callbacks necessary to assign the click events, I can't figure out how to access the scope of the remove() method again. Here is a code snippet:

```
define([ "dojo/dom", "dojo/json", "dojo/cookie", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/query", "dojo/on", "dojo/NodeList-dom" ],
    function(dom, json, cookie, array, query, on) {

        return {
            load : function(config) {
                var cart = this.get(config);
                if (cart != null) {
                    var cartDiv = dom.byId(config.cart.domWrapper);
                    // console.log("Shopping Cart: " + cart);
                    cartDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Shopping Cart</p>";
                    cartDiv.innerHTML += this.getHTML(cart);
                }

                query(".remove_item").forEach(function(node, i) {
                    on(query(".remove_item")[i], "click", function(event) {
                        console.log("Removing item " + i + " from cart...");
                        remove(config, i); //method does not exist at this scope
                    });                 
                });

            },

            remove : function(config, itemId) {
                                //....
            },
```

What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can "save" the class with

```
        load : function(config) {
            var self = this;
            //....
```

and then call "remove" with

```
//....    
on(query(".remove_item")[i], "click", function(event) {
                        console.log("Removing item " + i + " from cart...");
                        self.remove(config, i);
//....
```